# ruby - how to make a letter lowercase unless it comes after a comma or slash with regex

Tags: regex, ruby, task, mysql2

I am trying to clean a set of names from a mysql table using mysql2 gem in ruby code, and then add the cleaned names to the table in a new column. I was able to do the cleaning except for one condition: `Lowercasing all words, unless they come after a slash or after a comma or in parentheses`. Here's a sample piece of code:

```
def cleaning_names(client)
  q = "SELECT column_of_names FROM original_table;"
  names = client.query(q)
  names.map do |name|
    clean_name = "#{name["column_of_names"]"
  end
end
```

I used multiple `gsub`'s to do the rest of the cleaning, but I can't find out how to use regex (in a gsub maybe) in order to downcase letters, or to leave them alone if they come after a slash or comma.

For example, one of the names I want is: `'County Clerk/DeKalb County'` becomes `‘DeKalb County clerk’` or `"1st circuit judge, Circuit Court"` becomes `"1st circuit judge (Circuit Court)"`. My code fixed the order, but doesn't do the proper capitalization.

Thanks :-)

Comment: You may be looking for the following: `R = /(?<![,\\\/\p{L}])\p{L}+/; "Little Miss Muffet ,She Sat on A \\Tuffet".gsub(R) { |s| s.downcase } #=> "little miss muffet ,She sat on a \\Tuffet"`. This assumes you don't want to match a word that is immediately preceded by a comma, forward slash or backslash. `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter. `(?<![,\\\/\p{L}])` is a *negative lookbehind* that asserts that a word is not preceded by a comma, forward slash, backslash or letter (the latter needed to avoid matching, say, `"BC"` in `",ABC"`.

Comment: Lowercase everything, then uppercase only the letters immediate following `[/,]`, perhaps with a lookbehind.

Comment: If you don't want to match `"Abc"` in `", Abc"`, that is a different requirement. @Todd, presumably, `",ABc"` is to be left unchanged

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's the end result, not necessarily the easiest way to implement it. A lot of people use complicated regular expressions when there are easier ways, and I'm pointing that out. The question doesn't contain enough inputs/outputs to offer an optimal solution, and the whole question is a little hand-wavey as a result. Plus, "use regex" is often an X/Y solution; sometimes it's the best one, but it's hard to tell without real data, and even the expanded answer still leaves me with too many questions about the correct text fixtures and expectations.\

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and outputs for your final transformation. At least a handful of examples so it can be validated.